# How can I upgrade my Jira client?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to upgrade from 2.0.0-m2 to the latest version of the Java Jira client. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the pom for the project that currently depends on the Jira client in the following ways:

1. Tell your Maven to search the Atlassian public respositories by adding the following line to your pom:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>atlassian-public</id>
    <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

2. Add the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

3. Clean and build your project and handle any transitive dependency issues that might arise.